# word Breaking issue in css

Tags: html, line, break

I have a HTML Page with following structure

```
    <div class="cont">
    <ul class="=slides" id="slider2">
<li id="slides1_s0" class="slides1_on" 
style="display: block; float: left; position: relative; opacity: 1; z-index: 2; -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out; transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;">

<span id="stateLabel_22" 
style="font-size:15px;line-height:25px;">
Josef  is the Network Administrator in an organization. The organization is looking at upgrading all of its machines from Windows XP to Windows 7. Many of the managers are concerned that their Windows XP applications won ’ t be compatible with Windows 7. Which Windows 7 feature can you use to assure the managers that all of their Windows XP applications will continue to work?

</span>

</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My problem is that i have stored `&nbsp;` in database and which is binded to a control.
No in the sentence starting with  "Josef  is..." instead of space `&nbsp;` is there. 
Because of this reason my text is displayed as a long one and hence i applied `word-break: break-all;` to `ul` class.

Now the issue is that my text is breaking irrespective of the word. It displays like

```
Josef  is the Network Administrator in an organization. The organization is looking at upgrading al
l of its machines from Windows XP to Windows 7. Many of the managers are concerned that the
ir Windows XP applications
```

How can I fix it. Please help

Thanking you in advance

SAJ

Answer (score 1):

Call the span id in CSS and call the below CSS

`#span_id
{
white-space:nowrap;
}`

Comment: I have tried your answer. NO its displaying complete text in a single line which is too lengthy